# How to use json_contains with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to search json and extract data using json_contains. Where am I having trouble down there?

```php
    public function get_records($limit, $count)
    {
        return $this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(urun_kategori,'[18,19]')")->limit($limit, $count)->get("urunler")->result();
    }
```

```
urun_kategori
["18","19"]
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @Vickel I'm not getting any error messages. I can't pull the product from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an operator in your where clause try this sample

```
return $this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(urun_kategori,'[\"18\", \"19\"]')) > ", 0)->limit($limit, $count)->get("urunler")->result();
```

Also those numbers appear as strings so i added \" quotes around them to check for strings